# Group dataframe rows into a list

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I am having a data frame of the form

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, True], [3, 4, True], [5, 6, False], [7, 8, True], [9, 10, False], [11, 12, True], [13, 14, True]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

and I want to group the rows that have more than one consecutive `True` value into a list. More specifically, the output will be a list where the first item is `df.loc[0:2]` and the second item is `df.loc[5:6]`. Could you please suggest a way to do that using builtin functions?

Comment: If you use a numpy array this will convert the booleans to integers, is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the response. 0 and 1 integers are fine if the solution is easier.

Comment: It's actually easier with booleans. For my answer, if you have integers do `s = df['c'].astype(bool)` and use `s` in place of `df['c']` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, True], [3, 4, True], [5, 6, False], [7, 8, True], [9, 10, False], [11, 12, True], [13, 14, True]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

You can use `groupby` with groups starting with True:

```
m = (df['c']&~df['c'].shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum()

out = [d for _,d in df[df['c']].groupby(m) if len(d)>1]
```

Output:

```
[   a  b     c
 0  1  2  True
 1  3  4  True,
     a   b     c
 5  11  12  True
 6  13  14  True]
```

Comment: Not OP, can you please explain ` df['c']&~df['c'].shift(fill_value=False)`?

Comment: @DeathMetal apologize the brevity, I'm typing on a phone. if True and the previous row is not True, start a group (cumsum).

Comment: I am getting this error `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"`  when `out` is computed.

Comment: `df` has values 0 and 1 when created using the above definition.  So I applied your comment, i.e.,

`It's actually easier with booleans. For my answer, if you have integers do s = df['c'].astype(bool) and use s in place of df['c']`

Comment: May I ask why do we need `df[df['c']].groupby(m)` and not `df.groupby(m)` ?

Comment: @Darkmoor because you only want the rows with the 1s/True, right? Else you would also have the zeros

Comment: I found it strange because the size of `df[df['c']]`is smaller than that of `m` in `groupby`.

Comment: @Darkmoor yes this is the case, you could also slice `m` but this is not needed as `groupby` performs index alignment and ignores the extra indices ;)

Comment: Thanks. Finally, could you please write a few thing about the intuition of shifting and taking the cumulative sum? You gave a comment but I do not catch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `itertools.groupby`

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for k, g in groupby(zip(df.index, df['c']), itemgetter(1)):
    gs = list(g)
    if k and len(gs) > 1:
        idxs = list(map(itemgetter(0), gs))
        print(idxs)
```

```
[0, 1]
[5, 6]
```